# SQL Server 2012 Permission for bulk load are set, but still getting an error

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-agent

I have a user that has bulk load permissions set at the server level. I am logged into the server as that user. I can execute a query containing a bulk load with no problems whatsoever.

However, when I create a SQL Server Agent Job with that same query as a step and run as that same user, I get the error:

> "You do not have permissions to use the bulk load statement. [SQLSTATE 42000]

There are similar threads to this that explain how to set the permission, but the permission is already set and the user have all possible privileges including ownership.  What am I missing?

Comment: Check the job owner (normally, the job is executed under the owner's security context, with a few exceptions). Try setting the job owner to the login that you have used for testing(the one with the "administer bulk operations" permissions)

Comment: Thanks, they are the same (both me)